# Ubuntu and ASUS G750JM, GTX860M / Nvidia problems

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

This is my second thread, the other is on another website but that one is going no where and I don't think it gets enough attention so I'm posting here.

Has anyone gotten drivers to work the GTX860M in Ubuntu 14.04?  If so, how did you go about the task?

I'm running out of options, here's what I've tried:  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/771674/linux/ubuntu-freezes-at-login-with-the-gtx860ms-official-drivers-installed-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer works but it causes my trackpad to lock up the computer every once in a while.  It's a bug I believe ubuntu is working on.

1. From the terminal run to install the driver:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-settings
   ```
2. Then create a new configuration file by running (a new configuration file before reboot is CRUCIAL (you may get a warning but as long as a new configuration file is created you are okay to proceed to step 5):

   ```
   sudo nvidia-xconfig
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Download Bumblebee by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
   ```
5. Reboot
6. I suggest removing the ppa by typing (this is optional):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model cf computer, but with different graphics hardware - the Asus G750JM-T4019D Full HD, Haswell i7 4700HQ, 8GB, 1TB, nVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M 2GB.

I am successfully running Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome, but I didn't try to install any special driver during initial installation. I just let Ubuntu install its default drivers. My system is running quite stably and without problem, although I'm * probably * not getting ALL the functionality I possibly could if I had a driver specific to my system.

I read your thread at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/771674/linux/ubuntu-freezes-at-login-with-the-gtx860ms-official-drivers-installed-/

As far as I could understand, you opted to install special Nvidia drivers during your initial installation process.If I'm not mistaken about this, I'd recommend not doing so, and just using the Ubuntu 'default' driver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ubuntu's standard drivers only allow access to the Intel HD card ( I believe it is ) and not the secondary powerful NVidia GPU.