# Fans max on reboot

Tags: nvidia, reboot

Okay, on my own I discovered that following the instructions that I listed here: [Ubuntu and ASUS G750JM, GTX860M / Nvidia problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519372/ubuntu-and-asus-g750jm-gtx860m-nvidia-problems) my graphics card would work with my G750JM and it's GTX860M.  BUT occasionally, or maybe to be more accurate rarely when I reboot ubuntu, both the GPU and processor fans go full blast as it shuts down.  They don't stop no matter what I do, except powering off.  I can go into windows, go back into ubuntu, reboot endlessly.  They just keep running.

Any ideas or suggestions I could work with to fix this?  Anyone ever had this problem before, it may not be related to the graphics driver but that's when I noticed it.

Should I report this as a bug?  It only happens with Ubuntu so it has to be something in their OS causing it.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add acpi_osi=linux to the Linux commandline in /etc/default/grub configuration file.
Then run sudo update-grub to apply changes and reboot.

That will fix the fan issues and backlight problems.

Do NOT use 3rd party tools to control the fans on this laptop.

Comment: Thanks contributing an answer. Would you mind going a little further and also explain on how to make these changes?

Comment: I'll try to do this sometime today, and give it a few test boots.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with this laptop and Ubuntu. A workaround is to always turn the laptop off and then turn it on instead of rebooting. Maybe it is not perfect but still less frustrating.
I am wondering if you have the same issues when using windows.
I think it is related to BIOS, not graphics (or any) driver as they stop working during restart, so how could they start the fans? I don't know (yet) how fans speed is being regulated so I may be wrong...

Comment: Well I've never had a windows reboot cause the fans to run high.  It's always been about 1/10 times I reboot ubuntu and it only started when I installed those drivers.  So to answer your question, I'm not sure how those drivers could be doing it but it's all I got right now.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, please ensure that you're running the latest BIOS for your laptop.
You can download it from here: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=G750JM&p=3&s=521

Copy the .fd file to a FAT32 formatted USB drive, power down your laptop, insert the dongle, press Esc to enter startup menu, launch Enter Setup and flash the BIOS with EasyFlash. This will update the BIOS from the EFI environment.

It is NOT recommended to update system BIOS from within Windows. If it fails in Windows, you *WILL* brick your notebook. However, in EFI mode, should any part of the update fail (e.g verifying checksums), it will halt the upgrade and revert to the previous version.

The new BIOS' release notes are as follows:

1.Fix the bug that Fn+F8 has no function under Windows 7.

This is an ACPI related fix that updates the DSDT tables that WMI aware Operating Systems (e.g Windows 7) can use to adjust SMI triggered events such as hotkeys, backlight controls, etc.

An older revision of the BIOS (R205) reconfigures the thermal policy, and this fix is also valid for the new BIOS image.