# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't recognize Nvidia graphic card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I fresh installed **Ubuntu 14.04** on my new laptop and I'm struggling with the graphic card.
I have an **integrated Intel card + an NVIDIA GTX 860M coupled with optimus technology**.
I understand that optimus is a big source of problem with linux and I tried several of the proposed solutions to make my NVIDIA work.  Neither **bumblebee** nor **nvidia prime** seem to work. Ubuntu recognize only the **Intel** card:

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

**PS**: Need more information, Ask me
**PPS**: Sorry, as English is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: [Ubuntu and ASUS G750JM, GTX860M / Nvidia problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519372/ubuntu-and-asus-g750jm-gtx860m-nvidia-problems) ?

I have the same graphics card in my laptop and have serious issues still too.  Sometimes if I follow those instructions my the card works great other times,  it freezes randomly and if I don't run nvidia-xconfig I can't boot ubuntu anymore.  It's a very detrimental way of setting up the card but it is the best I have found and it took some work to figure out.

Comment: What laptop are you using?

Comment: It seems quite a risky solution. I'd prefer to try something else less "brave" before considering this option

Comment: I've done everything I could to get this thing working.  That was the only way it ever worked.

Comment: I found the problem with my instructions just needed to blacklist nouveau, if you follow them it should work just fine @Alessandro