# While using trackpad Ubuntu locks up graphics related

Tags: 14.04, graphics, freeze, 14.10, trackpad

My computer is locking up while I'm using the trackpad.  It seems to occur most after I install graphics drivers on a fresh install of ubuntu.  It has occured once on a fresh install of 14.10. It also occurs in 14.04 after I install graphic drivers.  I can't use ubuntu like this, because it's causing all sorts of problems.  Does anyone know a fix?

I'm running an asus republic of gamers g750jm with a gtx860m graphics card in it.  I don't believe I'm the only one with this problem and I found a solution that I believe works but it disables my trackpad's two-finger scroll.  The page is here: http://www.hackingnotcracking.com/?p=112 does anyone know how to avoid disabling the two finger scroll so I can test and see if this page's suggestion fixes my problem?

UPDATE: I did test that pages solutions they didn't work.  I still can't use Ubuntu unless I choose to not install drivers for my gtx860m,...  so now I just don't install graphic drivers now.

UPDATE: I am following the instructions laid out here: [Ubuntu and ASUS G750JM, GTX860M / Nvidia problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519372/ubuntu-and-asus-g750jm-gtx860m-nvidia-problems) and running into this problem.  Any advice or input may help the cause.

Still looking for a solution, I even set a bounty and nothing.  I'd open a bug ticket on it but I'm using edgers drivers.  When I try to install the nvidia drivers from their website lightdm won't even boot.

Comment: In order to even begin helping, we're going to need some more information such as computer model, graphics card, touchpad model, etc. Bascially, we need more specifics.

Comment: Okay I added some more info @githlar

Comment: Since this would seem to be a Nouveau-specific problem, I would recommend installing the drivers from Geforce.com (especially since you are using a new NVIDIA card that isn't supported by the Nouveau drivers, no 3D acceleration for Tesla-based cards) and see if that helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: I've already been through that, they never would work I ended up having to solve the issue myself by doing http://askubuntu.com/questions/519372/ubuntu-and-asus-g750jm-gtx860m-nvidia-problems/521005#521005 the stuff listed on that page...  blacklisting the nouveau drivers isn't really necessary however.  But after I do that stuff is when I experience the problem.  @githlar

Comment: Yep, that is essentially doing the same thing as installing the drivers from the Geforce site (Xorg Edgers has the most updated drivers -- just like the site), except that Bumblebee was installed as well for hybrid Intel HD/Nvidia configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on trackpad while using keyboard in settings, I found this answer online and so far it has resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problems on a laptop with GTX 860M, Ubuntu 14.04. I had the mouse cursor freeze (actually it must have been `lightdm` locking up) due to having the wrong graphics driver active. I had tried with the one from GeForce.com without any luck. Here is how I eventually made it work:

First, make sure drivers from GeForce.com are uninstalled (if you have them installed, run the installation file again with the `--uninstall` flag).

Then, update your sources, purge any packages with reference to `nvidia` and `bumblebee`. Install `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-340`. Run `nvidia-xconfig` and reboot. Here are the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```

Note: if you have trouble using the graphical interface, press `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1]` and log in on the first cli interface. If needed, enter `sudo service lightdm stop` to stop the graphical interface before running the above commands.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing.

Comment: Actually this is not exactly what I've been doing, but you see, as soon as I install nvidia-340 the problems start occuring.  I was using bumblebee and nvidia-340...  having these problems.

Comment: I also got problems using bumblebee. Have you tried the combo nvidia-prime and nvidia-340 (or nvidia-current)?

Comment: I just tried it- didn't work either